# Cross-correlation of massive arrays

Tags: cross-correlation

I have 16 1D arrays with approximately 10-11 million double-precision elements each. I need to execute a cross-correlation across them, i.e., 1 with 2, 1 with 3, ..., 1 with 16, 2 with 3, 2 with 4, ..., 2 with 16, and so on. This cannot be done efficiently on my MacBook Intel Core 2 duo 2.4 GHz, with 4GB of RAM. My question is, what is the typical approach, if not brute force (faster processor, more RAM) that people use to overcome this problem, or problems like it?

I asked this question on Stack Overflow a few minutes ago, but I realized that there might be more people here who have dealt with this particular problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised this isn't possible, actually. I'm running a similar setup to you (8GB instead of 4, but I doubt that makes a difference here) and I see (using R here):

```
> x=runif(1e7)
> y=runif(1e7)
> system.time(cor(x,y))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.129   0.001   0.128
```

So for (16 choose 2) = 120 of these computations, that'd be around 15 seconds. Are you perhaps computing the correlations via an inefficient loop in whatever language you're using, instead of using the built-in function? Or is the computation you're doing more complicated for some reason?

EDIT: storing the values as columns of a matrix, the computation is even simpler and faster:

```
> X = matrix(runif(16*1e7), ncol=16)
> system.time(cor(X))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.684   0.003   3.687
```

Comment: In R on a similarly specced machine: `a <- matrix(rnorm(1e7 * 16), 1e7, 16); system.time(cor(a))` takes about 32 seconds. I think there's something funny going on here.

Comment: I'm using NumPy, but I figured that the choice of software wouldn't matter in this case. I'm beginning to think it might. NumPy's `correlate` function (actually an instance method on `ndarray` objects) is a native C function that directly calculates the cross correlation, i.e., not using fft identities. However, seeing that R can do it in about 5 seconds on my machine makes me think that this is a very bad oversight in the choice of implementation of `correlate`. However, even a stupid simple version of autocorrelation using the fft identities in Python still takes ~18s, which is unacceptable.

Comment: I should say that the 18s time was for the autocorrelation of a single ~1e7 element array.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using multiple cores: the snow package allows you to build a cluster on the same machine or on multiple computers in your network. Then you can use parLapply() to distribute the cor() function. It works exactly like lapply() except it will send each cor() call to a different process in the cluster.